# How to use weights in custom measure for mlr?

Tags: r, mlr

When defining a new measure using `mlr::makeMeasure`, in particular

```
mlr::makeMeasure(
    fun = function(task, model, pred, feats, extra.args) { } 
)
```

I know I can access the truth with `pred$data$truth` and the predictions with `pred$data$response`, but how can I access the weights if they were supplied with the original task?

I don't think the `pred` object has the weights, but if that's true then I can't see a way of accessing the weights for the observations that have been used for predict.

I think I can't use the weights from the `task` object because they are for the entire training set, not the subset used in - for example - cross validation.

Comment: It sounds like [`makeCostMeasure()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mlr/versions/2.13/topics/makeCostMeasure) does what you're looking for.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff the task I'm working on is a regression task, could I adapt `makeCostMeasure()` to that situation?

Comment: In general yes, but you'd likely need to modify the source.